# How to create non standard @property with custom parameters in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, properties, methods

I want to use a custom property to interact between controllers. Or do I have to use methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you create property a setter and getter is created automatically
  for you.
- If you want to do some custom action along with setting or getting
  value you can write a method.
- Also you can use `@public` modifier to make your member visible to
  other class.

Comment: So if i mark some method or @property public i may access it from other controller?

Comment: ok, thanx a lot, i read somewhere that its not possible to use methods from other controller..nice that it was wrong.